# Libpuzzle PHP 5

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-extension

I'm trying to install `libpuzzle` onto my ubuntu server.

I have `php5` installed as well as the `GD` Library.

I used the repository for `libpuzzle`

```
sudo apt-get install libpuzzle-php
```

Didn't get any errors.

When i run

```
phpinfo();
```

`Libpuzzle` shows up, but there is nothing under it, and the pages using the library don't run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, most php modules come with configuration options. Did you take a look at those? You probably have to enable stuff. Those things are typically kept in a separate .ini style file (part of the installed package). Although debian is pretty old fashioned in this, so you might also find them in the main php.ini file. Grep for "puzzle" in phps configuration files, I'd suggest.

Comment: According to the documentation of that library there are indeed no configuration options. So nothing will show up in the `phpinfo()` output. So the question is: what is not working? Your "the pages don't run" does not help here. What does that mean? You get an error? An empty page? Does the universe implode? Start by taking a look into the http servers error log file I'd say...

Comment: There was nothing in the php.ini for libpuzzle. There is a libpuzzle.ini in the "mods-available" folder that just contains

`;configuration for php libpuzzle module`
`extension=libpuzzle.so`

Comment: the page doesn't run, as in it's blank.

But if there are no configurations, then there has to be something else wrong on my end. Error log here i come!

Comment: OK, so the package brings a separate configuration file as I mentioned in my first comment and its content is fine according to the documentation as mentioned in my last comment. If you get a blank page then you certainly should find something in the error log file, some error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake on my part. I checked the `error log` and saw the line

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

I had then realized I didn't set the proper permissions for the files I was using in the script and the script itself.

I just set the permissions with `chmod`, and every worked fine.